# How to append new element to two different places JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My goal is to append a new element to two difference places. I have two divs with IDs div1 and div2. I want to append a newly created span element to both divs.

```
document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(span);
```

This works fine, but the problem is this

```
document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(span);
```

When the second `appendChild` is run, it removes the span from div1. How can I add the span element to both places?

(To visualize the execution, I added a `setTimeout`)

```js
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));

document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(span);
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(span);
}, 3000)
```

```css
#div1 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: red;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Create 2 span elements. One element cannot exist in two places in the DOM.

Comment: does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 4):

Use the cloneNode method on the existing span:

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));

document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(span);
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(span.cloneNode(true));
}, 3000)
```

```css
#div1 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: red;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One element cannot exist in two places in the DOM.
You can create the node two times or clone de node

```
    document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(createSpan());
    setTimeout(() => {
       document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(createSpan());
    }, 3000)

    function createSpan () {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));
      return span
    }
```

OR

```
    const span = createSpan();

    document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(span);
    setTimeout(() => {
       document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(span.cloneNode(true));
    }, 3000)

    function createSpan () {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));
      return span
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A DOM element can only be a child to one and only other DOM element.
You're appending the span element you've created to the first div, and then you're appending it to the second one. Common sense has it so that the span is then removed from the first div and moved to the second one.
You can achieve what you want by doing the following.

```js
const span = document.createElement('span');

    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));
    document.querySelector('#div1').appendChild(span);
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('#div2').appendChild(span.cloneNode(true));
    }, 3000);
```

```css
#div1 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: red;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 3px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```